# How To Briefly Pasue Animation Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, css-animations, loading, mousewheel

I'm trying to briefly pause my loading animation as I want it to reset by scroll but I don't want to e able to do it straight away.

```
<div id="progressbar">
  <div id="loading" class="run-animation"></div>
</div>

    <script>

"use strict";

var element = document.getElementById("loading");

document.addEventListener("mousewheel", function(e){
  e.preventDefault;

  void element.offsetWidth;
  element.classList.add("run-animation");
}, false);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new class `pause-animation` like below. And whenever you want to pause your element, just add this class to element like `element.classList.add("pause-animation")`. You can also remove it to play.

```
.pause-animation{
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply.

The animation needs to run again. I main reason why i want a delay is so that the user doesn't constantly reload the loading bar.